# didDiscoverPeripheral called very slowly

Tags: ios, swift, macos, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a question regarding CoreBluetooth programming in **Mac OS X**. I have some BLE beacons here that I want to detect. When I execute similar code on my iPhone, it seems to work just fine, but when I try this on my Mac, it seems to only notify of beacons in the neighbourhood every two seconds or so (or even more, but at least 2 seconds). The beacons are beaconing every 500ms, so I would expect to be notified every 500ms.

Is there someone out there who knows how I can tell Mac OS to be a little stricter with reporting the beacons?

I must say I'm quite new to Swift, so all comments on style will also be appreciated.

```
import Foundation
import CoreBluetooth

class CentralManagerDelegate : NSObject, CBCentralManagerDelegate {
    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(central: CBCentralManager) {
        if central.state == .PoweredOn {
            central.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(nil, options: [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey : "YES"])
            print("Started scanning")
        }
        else {
            central.stopScan()
        }

    }
    func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : AnyObject], RSSI: NSNumber) {
        print("Beacon found with RSSI: " + RSSI.stringValue);
    }
}

var _centralManagerDelegate = CentralManagerDelegate()
var _centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: _centralManagerDelegate, queue: dispatch_get_main_queue())

while true {
    dispatch_main()
}
```

Comment: Were you able to find out why this is the case? I am also observing this kind of behavior.

Comment: No, since my final product would run on smartphones, I just switched to only testing on iPhone. Probably you're better of asking on an Apple forum. I'm still interested in the solution, though ;)